# How to use webpack-stream with gulp-inject?

Tags: webpack, gulp-inject

I have two tasks set up. A webpack task and a inject task.

Webpack:

```
gulp.task('webpack', (done) => {
  gulp.src('./src/app/app.module.js')
    .pipe(plugins.webpack({
      module: {
        loaders: [
          { test: /\.html$/, loaders: ["html"]},
          { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/, loaders: ['babel-loader']}
        ]
      }
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp/scripts/'))
    done();
})
```

Inject:

```
gulp.task('inject', ['webpack'], () => {
  var globalSources = gulp.src(['.tmp/scripts/*.js'], {read: false});
  return gulp.src('src/index.html')
    .pipe(plugins.plumber())
    .pipe(plugins.inject(globalSources, {
      addRootSlash: false,
      addPrefix: '.',
      ignorePath: '.tmp'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp/'));
})
```

I've found that webpack task will say it's done before it's placed the streamed file into the .tmp/scripts folder. Therefore when inject carries on there's no file to inject.

Is webpack-stream outputting it's own callback that's being used before the done()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call the `done()` right after starting the stream, it may look differently because you left off the semi-colon at the end of the stream and you indented `done()` too much. What you really have is:

```
gulp.task('webpack', (done) => {
  gulp.src('./src/app/app.module.js')
    .pipe(plugins.webpack(/* config */))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp/scripts/'));
  done();
})
```

What you want to do is call done within the stream (at the end of the pipeline). According to the docs for [Async task support](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#async-task-support) you can use `.on('end', callback)` to achieve that. So the full task would look like this:

```
gulp.task('webpack', (done) => {
  gulp.src('./src/app/app.module.js')
    .pipe(plugins.webpack({
      module: {
        loaders: [
          { test: /\.html$/, loaders: ["html"]},
          { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/, loaders: ['babel-loader']}
        ]
      }
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp/scripts/'))
    .on('end', done)
})
```

Comment: Ah yes. I suspected the done call might be in the wrong place. Works correctly now.